# Testing for differences in variation between variables

Tags: r, variance, vector-autoregression

I am trying to find out whether it is true that variation in expenditure is greater, for more narrow subsets. e.g. is it more likely that an individual buys an orange instead of an apple, than it is for him to buy a potato instead of an apple.

So far i have used var() and f-tests(while i believe f-tests aren't really applicable to my problem either). I would however like to use more applicable models if that is possible. Every test or class of models i can find however, are meant to compare two samples' variances. While I want to test for each observation, whether they are more likely to go for alternatives, the more constrained the subset is.

I have a dataframe, with variables on multiple levels (drinks, soda, types of coke), and two time points of observation. As far as I am aware, two time points are not enough for a time-series analysis, and a repeated measures anova is not really applicable either.

Could anyone point me to a resource or name of a test / type of model that could help me solve the problem? or, are var() and var.test() the only tools that are applicable?